# Injecting data resolved models at runtime with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am building an app with Simple Injector in WPF and I have run into the issue where I want to resolve my Models to inject into my ViewModels at runtime. For instance, say I have a window to edit users that requires a ViewModel with a User Model. This user model is selected from a list and then injected into the ViewModel's constructor. How would I get this data into the ViewModel with Simple Injector? Is that even possible? I figure if it is possible I would use some form of factory maybe? I was debating on using Simple Injector for everything except my MVVM components as a workaround--that is unless I can find a good solution.

If I should post some example code or anything like that to give a more clear definition of the problem, let me know. This is my first run with a DI Container and I want to understand how to best design my application with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the prefered approach what you're aiming for is indeed not possible. That is because your design is not optimal. As you can read [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) injecting runtime data in the components of your application is an anti-pattern.

The model for editing your users is runtime data and should thus flow through your application via method injection.

So you could solve this like:

```
public interface IViewModel<T>
{
    void EditItem(T item);
}

class UserEditViewModel : IViewModel<User>
{
    public void EditItem(User item)
    {
        // bind properties etc...
    }
}
```

You would typically inject the `IViewModel<User>` in your user master viewmodel.

Based on [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) and [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) design you can imagine a far more flexible solution. If you would see editing a user as performing a command which you just fire and returns when it's finished, you could define a infrastructal component a la the `QueryProcessor` from the link. This would become an `EditProcessor` which handles all your edit operations in your application. An implementation is pretty simple and would look something like:

```
class EditProcessor : IEditProcessor
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public EditProcessor(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void EditItem<T>(T item)
    {
        var viewModel = typeof (IViewModel<>).MakeGenericType(typeof (T));
        dynamic instance = container.GetInstance(viewModel);

        instance.EditItem((dynamic) item);
    }
}
```

Now everywhere you need to edit some model, you only inject `IEditProcessor` and call

```
this.editProcessor.EditItem(yourItem);
```

This simple implementation of an `EditProcessor` can be extended will all kinds of nice features like making a backup of the item before editing, so the user could cancel the editform for example.

If you use some MVVM toolkit to bind your view to your viewmodel this would also be the place to bring your DI container and the MVVM toolkit interact with eachother nicely.

Comment: I do have a question on this. How do you suppose I get my view to tie into this model? Say I have a window with a constructor that takes in IViewModel<T>, what should I do to hook everything up, or should I have the view model reference the window? I have seen that happen on occasion. I do not use an MVVM toolkit, so I need to figure this all out manually.

Comment: Given a certain ViewModel, how would you find the correct View for it? Do you have some kind of convention? I guess, based on your question you don't. There are severals ways to do this. If you give me some direction I can edit my answer with some examples

Comment: Right now I have no "real" convention. I am naming them the same in practice. For example, EditUserView will have the EditUserViewModel. From what I understand of Prism--and this may not be exactly true--it would match the two by the name. I'm not 100% fond of that because of the clear restriction on naming. Is that enough information? Is there a more friendly way than naming?

Comment: Naming a.k.a. [convention over configuration](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) is the most common practice. Other options would involve writing and maintaning code, which could be your choice ofcourse. You could think of maintaining a dictionary which binds the viewmodels to the views.

Comment: Hmm, okay. You gave me a few ideas. Thanks for the response! You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't inject models into your ViewModel.

Sounds more like you need an event aggregator/messanger. You would inject the event aggregator into your view models and subscribe to a certain event and rise it form another ViewModel.

```
public class CustomersViewModel 
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public CustomersViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
    {
        if(eventAggregator==null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("eventAggregator");
        }

        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    private Customer selectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return selectedCustomer; }
        set 
        {
            if(selectedCustomer!=value) 
            {
                selectedCustomer = value;
                eventAggregator.Publish(new CustomerSelectedEvent(selectedCustomer);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerOrdersViewModel 
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private readonly IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    private ObservableCollection<Order> orders;
    public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders {
        get { return orders; } 
        set 
        {
            if(orders != value)
            {
                orders = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Orders");
            }
        }
    }

    public CustomerDetailViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IOrderRepository orderRepository) 
    {
        if(eventAggregator==null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("eventAggregator");
        }

        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.Subscribe<CustomerSelectedEvent>(OnCustomerSelected);
        ...
    }

    private async void OnCustomerSelected(CustomerSelectedEvent event) 
    {
        Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(await orderRepository.GetOrdersByCustomer(event.Customer.Id);
    }
}
```

Where the `SelectedCustomerEvent` would be a simple POCO class.

```
public class SelectedCustomerEvent 
{
    public Customer Customer { get; }

    public SelectedCustomerEvent(Customer customer) 
    {
        // C# 6.0, otherwise add a private setter
        Customer = customer;
    }
}
```

The implementation of the event aggregator is a bit out of the scope, but there are frameworks that come with messanger/event aggregators (Prism PubSubEvents for example).

Comment: Interesting approach. I assumed my concept was flawed, in a way, but I wasn't sure how or a good way to go about replacing it. Thanks!

Comment: How would you show a modal dialog for editing a user using this approach?

Comment: That's a tricky part. One way to do it is by using a Dialog or navigation service, you pass the interface in your ViewModel Layer and do the concrete implementation in your View/Application assembly (assuming you are enforcing MVVM by splitting your app into at least 3 assemblies for model, viewmodel and view/application). Another approach is seen in Prism 5.0/6.0 Framework, with InteractionRequest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx it's bit hard to get started with, but can be pretty powerful once you get the grip of it

Comment: Or just use an infrastructural component like the EditProcessor from my answer. Keeps things simple and indepent from all kinds of frameworks. I inject a DialogHandler in the EditProcessor and fire from there.